# Appcelerator module not loading (android canvas)

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, appcelerator

I have successfully installed the com.wwl.canvas module for Appcelerator Titanium but I am unable to use it.  When I run my program, it immediately exits with the following error:

`[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (KrollRuntimeThread) [54,260] Sending event: exception on thread: KrollRuntimeThread msg:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load com.wwl.canvas from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/ci.useek.app-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/ci.useek.app-2]: findLibrary returned null; Titanium 3.4.1,2014/11/13 13:33,5982e8f
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load com.wwl.canvas from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/ci.useek.app-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/ci.useek.app-2]: findLibrary returned null
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.loadExternalModules(V8Runtime.java:123)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:90)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:185)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:109)`

I have module installed in my tiapp.xml file and when I build the app I see the module get pulled in:

`[DEBUG] :  Detected android module: com.wwl.canvas 1.0 @ /Users/kaz/scratch/useek_mobile_phase_2/modules/android/com.wwl.canvas/1.0`

The module was installed from here: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5941

Comment: Have you checked that all files are in the module folder? I had a very similar issue caused by some missing files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and recompile the module and it works fine... hope all is well, ping me if you run into additional issues.

[image]

Comment: The problem was just running the module in the x86 emulator.  Found this text in the log and that pointed me in the right direction: 

`
[WARN] :   The module com.wwl.canvas does not support the ABI: x86
[WARN] :   It only supports the following ABIs: armeabi, armeabi-v7a
[WARN] :   Your application will most likely encounter issues
`